# How to hide links in Stack Overflow answers from search engines?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, search-engine

Some of my previous questions on Stack Overflow contain test links to client websites. However, my client would prefer these links not to show in google. Is there a way to do this without hindering the question for future users? .

Comment: Edit the questions to remove the links. Google will eventually pick up on the change. And in the future don't use links to actual client sites for questions. Use fiddles/codepads to demonstrate problems, or put the sample pages on an unrelated server.

Comment: I read your question like this: "I painted my client's name in all signs on this street. Is there a way to avoid people from reading my client's name without removing the client's name from the signs?"

Comment: Main issue is that if they are deleted they actually won't show up in google which Marc B answered so that's all ok. I'll be sure to change all links to another 'test' domain. cheersy

Comment: @MarcB Could you make that comment into an answer?

Comment: Ah, if I'm not wrong,all links have rel="nofollow", right? Doesn't it mean every link posted by user is/are ignored?

Comment: You don't post them in the first place.  Also, asking people to go to a website to fix your bug is not acceptable here.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still happens *all the time.*

Comment: @genesis `nofollow` doesn't mean they'll be hidden

Answer (score 16):

Edit the questions to remove the links. Google will eventually pick up on the change. And in the future don't use links to actual client sites for questions. Use fiddles/codepads to demonstrate problems, or put the sample pages on an unrelated server.

Answer (score 8):

If it *really* needs to completely vanish (e.g. serious information leak through just the URL alone) you can make an edit and then flag for a <strike>moderator</strike> developer to make the previous versions vanish entirely from the history. (I've only done this once, after approving an edit that removed a real, working API key from an answer).

I think that's probably not productive use of moderator/developer time though if there's going to be 10s or even 100s of these. An edit combined with a firewall/DNS change is probably most appropriate to make it disappear. If you control the site google have [a number of ways of removing it](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/url-removal-explained-part-i-urls.html) from their side too.

As a side note: If you post lots of links to your clients site in lots of questions it looks a lot like spammy promotion of the site - it would be better all round if the question was more abstract. This would also have the side benefit of probably making it more useful to future visitors.

Comment: ♦ moderators can't remove previous version histories, only SE devs can do that...

Comment: @studiohack - I did wonder; it took longer to happen than usual when I raised that flag, but it did happen in the end so I assumed it was the correct thing to do.

Comment: it is the correct thing to do, it took longer because the mods called a dev over to do the job.