# Protecting users from their own ignorance

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

If a user mistakenly (or in ignorance) posts something which contains sensitive data (eg account logins) is there a way to remove the sensitive data so that it is permanently deleted?  Editing the post is the obvious first step, but the edit history will still contain sensitive information.

Do moderators have access to tools to remove data **swiftly** and **permanently**?

Comment: A dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112350/how-to-permanently-delete-questions-that-contain-sensitive-information, which is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information.

Comment: We have a procedure, but nothing you put online is truly ever gone.  Not when Google indexes your site every other second.

Comment: @Won't and GSerg, thanks. I have flagged (about four hours ago) and sent email (about 1 hour ago), but at the time of writing, the information still remains.

Comment: @PaulG: We've got over 200 flags in the queue.  It just doesn't happen all that fast.  If you can, delete the question.  I'm not sure if anyone has acted on the flag yet (I haven't spent any time in the queue today, unfortunately).  I'll try to find the flag now.